# Hiding C# XML Documentation

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using the C# XML style of documentation in my latest project (eg using `///<summary>` stuff). I find this makes the source code a pain to read as it just becomes so long. Is there a way in Visual Studio to auto-collapse just these or do I have to use the collapse to definitions and re-expand functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look here at the following post, I think it should help

http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/30?n=collapse-all-xml-comments-in-vb-net-or-c

Comment: Exactly what I needed in theory, doesn't seem 100% reliable but better than nowt!